# How to do File handling in FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos

I wrote a driver on linux, now i want to port it to freeRTOS, here i am getting trouble.
such as file handling API like fseek, opendir, readdir, fopen, fwrite, ftell how to find alternate in freeRTOS.

Comment: What kind of driver are you trying to port? It's a POSIX driver? What's your file system lib?

Comment: i am trying to port DLNA driver, linux specific code is written separately so that only those api i have to change while porting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [FreeRTOS+IO](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_IO/FreeRTOS_Plus_IO.shtml).

But as you are referring to `opendir()`, `readdir`, etc, i suppose you need a File System library, and if it's the case, this is an excellent one : [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html).

Should not be difficult to make FatFs work with FreeRTOS+IO.